# Java configuration in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, configuration, guice, constructor-injection

I have classes `A`, `B` and their implementation `AImpl`, `BImpl`.

```
interface A {
}
interface B {
}
interface C {
}
class AImpl{
    @Inject
    AImpl(B b){}
}
class BImpl{
    @Inject
    BImpl(String foo, C c){}
}
class CImpl{
}
```

To configure dependencies in Guice I would write smt like

```
bind(A.class).to(AImpl);
bind(C.class).to(CImpl);
@Provides B provideB(C c){
   return new BImpl("foo", c)
}
```

In spring I can do smt like

```
@Bean public A a() {
    return new AImpl(b())
}
@Bean public B b() {
    return new BImpl("foo", c());
}
@Bean public C c() {
    return new CImpl();
}
```

There are several downsides

- I should write that AImpl needs B in 2 places (constructor and config).
- I should write more code (CImp and AImpl requires method creation instead of one expression)

Are there any way to impruve my spring configuration without doing xml?

**upd**
I don't want to polute my classes with spring related annotations like @Component either. And I would prefer constructor injection to any kind of other injections. Scanning is not preferable solution too.
So, can I do Spring in Guice way?

**upd2**

**So** I want archive

- Autowiring
- Constructor-injection

Without

- XML
- PathScan

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating Bean using java code you can use Autowiring. You can define ComponentScan in your java configuration. You do not need to use any XML file.

Comment: Can I do autowiring without scaning and xml in Spring?

Comment: I have not come across any such solution. The autowiring is done by Spring container based on what packages you define in the ComponentScan and its done once at the time of initialization. Not sure what problem you are trying to solve by avoiding this.

Comment: It seems challeging for me to do testing when componentScan presented. Beside that, it just seems like a bad practice for me.

Comment: Spring provides excellent test framework. I have never faced any problem. If you can highlight the exact issue then I can try to help. I find ComponentScan to be of great help as otherwise every time you need to write or amend code to create new beans and managing dependencies. Its flexible as well.

Answer (score 0):

This creates beans OK without xml and polluting beans with Spring annotation:

```
interface A {
}

interface B {
}

interface C {
}

class AImpl implements A {
    AImpl(B b) {
    }
}

class BImpl implements B {
    BImpl(String foo, C c) {
    }
}

class CImpl implements C {
}

@Configuration
class Config {
    @Bean public A a() {
        return new AImpl(b());
    }

    @Bean public B b() {
        return new BImpl("foo", c());
    }

    @Bean public C c() {
        return new CImpl();
    }
}

public class T1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how it works now. But how I can autowire `B` into `AImpl`?